# searching for and updating a wildcard/unicode chacracter using SQL

Tags: sql, unicode

I have a string stored in a SQL databse that contains a wildcard unicode character followed by whitepsapce before the text I suspect in an attempt to try and mock right to left text and I need to remove the wildcard character however attemptng to search for the characters with a like clause does not locate it correctly.

I have tried using the square brackets method too combined with the like clause and this returns to me nothing. I have hundreds of these that I need to update.

```
                                                           يستمع المتعلم بانتباه مُتَّبعا توجيهات مكونة من خطوة أو خطوتين.
```

The character is actually viewed as a small box with a question mark inside of it although when copied and then pasted it's simply small box as per the example above.

```
UPDATE
[Application].[Database].[Table]
set
[Name] = REPLACE ([Name], N'%%',  N'% %')
where 
[Name]  LIKE N'%%'
```

The above query currently does not update the value by removing the unwanted character.

Is there any way to replace this wildcard chracter using only SQL?

Comment: my SELECT statement does return only those values that contain the offending character. the UPDATE statement does not remove the character

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REPLACE ([Name], N'%%',  N'% %')
```

looks for the substring `'%%'`. This does not exist in the string however. You want

```
REPLACE ([Name], N'',  N' ')
```

instead. This replaces all `''` with blanks.